# Facebook is not Logout programatically in Objective C With FBSDKLoginManager LogOut Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-debugger

Hi please check this code for integration of Facebook but i cannot login with different Facebook user

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_likes",@"user_groups",@"user_managed_groups"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if ([result.declinedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]) {
        NSLog(@"declained permissions");
    } else {
        if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,email,picture.type(large),groups" forKey:@"fields"]]
             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                 if (error==nil) {

                     NSString *facebookToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;
                     NSLog(@"user token is = %@",facebookToken);
                 }else {

                     NSLog(@"facebook erro : %@ ",error);
                 }
             }];
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to "log out" the current user from the previous **Facebook Login** you must revoke their access to the application. In other words, you `DELETE` their previous permission.

This will ensure that upon logging out and logging *back* in, the user will be prompted to *re-authenticate* themselves **and** *re-allow* permission to the application.

---

[from Facebook's developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions)

> **Revoke Login**
>
> You can revoke all privileges for an app, by making a Graph API call that deletes all permissions. Use the code in Revoke Permissions and change the request's path to /me/permissions.

**Objective-C**

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" parameters:nil
                                   HTTPMethod:@"DELETE"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // ... Do anything here upon finishing this call.
}];
```

**Swift**

```
let deletepermission = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/permissions/", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "DELETE")
    deletepermission.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection,result,error)-> Void in            
        println("the delete permission is \(result)")

    })
```